# User asks question but his profile is 'page not found'

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://askubuntu.com/users/257962/user257962) asks [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457617/is-there-any-gui-app-to-create-desktop-files) and 30 secs later I go to check out his/her profile only to face the 'Page not found' error.

What is the explanation behind that?

Comment: Oh, never mind. The link in the question has become inactive. I guess he was deleted or something.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the user deleted themselves. Why? Who knows.

Comment: "User deleted themselves". Wait, we can't delete our accounts on our own, we need to contact the SE Team for deletion of accounts. What am I missing? Or, did the user contact them soon after asking the question and the SE Team fulfilled the request extremely quickly? That would be a bit bizarre if happened!

Comment: @Aditya It's listed as a self-deletion without help from anybody else. It's probably a circumstance unique to new users without any reputation.